# Line jump with openssl s_client -connect command when using CAfile

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, hsm

I am trying to connect with some HSM cloud service using a specific url:port provided by the service vendor. The connection works fine if CAfile is omited from the syntax of the s_client -connect command. However, when included, the prompt simply shows a line jump (not even an error message).

-Certs have been tested several times by HSM cloud service provider.

-Firewalls on both ends have been tested and all necessary whitelisting has been completed.

Client Server info:

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

Debian 4.9.168-1

NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"

VERSION_ID="9"

VERSION="9 (stretch)"

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64

Architecture: x86-64

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j 20 Nov 2018

*curl results:

> curl -v us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com:1111
>
> Rebuilt URL to: us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com:1111/ Trying 19*.5*.7*.7*... > TCP_NODELAY set Connected to us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com (19*.5*.7*.7*) port > 1111 (#0) GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com:1111> User-Agent: > curl/7.52.1 Accept: /
>
> Curl_http_done: called premature == 0 Empty reply from server Connection #0 to > host us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com left intact curl: (52) Empty reply from server

*Command openssl s_client -connect without CAfile:

> openssl s_client -connect us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com:1111 -cert signed_cert.pem -key ssl-privatekey.pem -CApath . -tls1_1
>
> CONNECTED(00000003) ... ... verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain

(This error:num=19, I assume is because CAfile has been omited).

Then it changes to interactive mode and I am able to communicate with HSM's proprietary API.

*Command openssl s_client -connect WITH CAfile:

> openssl s_client -connect us01hsm01test.hsmprovider.com:1111 -cert signed_cert.pem -key ssl-privatekey.pem -CApath ./ -CAfile CA_Tree.pem -tls1_1
>
> user@debianserver:~$

It simply jumps a line and it doesn't even show an error message.

Comment: It is hard to read since the question is just formatted badly. But for me it looks like the behavior is the same as with curl, i.e. the server simply closes the connection without any response. My guess is though that you don't show the full output, i.e. there should be at least a CONNECTED for the version wit `-CAfile` too. Given the current state of the question please don't expect much of useful help. To improve the question please start with formatting it properly, add information from `openssl ... -debug` (properly formatted) and ideally have something which can be reproduced by others.

Comment: Thanks so much Steffen. I will improve the formatting of my questions.